# Camera preview orientation is in landscape but device is in portrait

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-camera2

I am having a problem with the orientation of the preview in camera2 API. Even though the device is in portrait mode, the preview I am getting is in landscape. To be more precise, the sensor rotation I am getting is 90 and so accordingly, the sensor data is also getting mapped at 90. The observations are on the emulator (Nexus 5).

```
private void startPreview() {
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                            null, mBackgroundHanlder);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for(String cameraId: cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
                    == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

            int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
            boolean swapRotation = mTotalRotation == 90 || mTotalRotation == 270;
            int rotatedWidth = width;
            int rotatedHeight = height;

            if (swapRotation) {
                rotatedHeight = width;
                rotatedWidth = height;
            }
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
            mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);

            mcameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
    int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
    deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
    return (sensorOrientation+deviceOrientation+360)%360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually applying the rotation transform to your output frames.  Just swapping the width/height doesn't do anything, because in general the camera only supports landscape resolutions.

You need to use the TextureView's getTransform and setTransform functions to add the necessary rotation.

Specifically:

1. Read in the current transform with getTransform
2. Multiply that transform by the necessary rotation transform you calculate based on your UI orientation
3. Set that as the TextureView transform with setTransform

The code for the Camera2Basic sample app may help here, though I'm not sure it's set up to do portrait orientation: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

Comment: should we set for landscape `texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)` and `texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width)` for portrait? or it should be always `texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)`?